# ionic build ios failed,always get export failed

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic2

> ** EXPORT FAILED **
>
> Error: Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args:
>   -exportArchive,-archivePath,MyApp.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/yeezy/cbe/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/yeezy/cbe/platforms/ios/build/device

this my ionic info;

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.3.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms               : ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.3
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002 
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13
```

somebody help?

Comment: What did you edit? @suraj

Comment: I put the error message within a block qoute..nothing else..

Comment: can u solve my problem plz @suraj

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with my ionic1 test app. What happened to me was first I had to change the development team in xcode. Then, still in xcode, I updated the bundle identifier. Finally to resolve my issue I changed the config.xml file that is at the root of my ionic app. I changed the id attribute of the widget element to match the bundle identifier that I set in xcode.

[image: Changing the Development team in xcode]
[image: Changing the Bundle Identifier]
[image: Changing config.xml to match Bundle Identifier]